# How to calculate total price using keyup function in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys I just want to ask how can I perform an automatically computation using jquery?
Like for example if I have 3 textbox. The textbox 1 is for quantity and textbox 2 is for price and textbox 3 is for result. When the user entered a value in textbox 1 and textbox 2 the textbox 3 will automatically solve the computation (price * quantity). If the user That's all guys I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Here's my html code.

```
<tr>
   <td><input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value='' />
   <td><input type='text' name='price' id='price' value='' />
   <td><input type='text' name='total' id='total' value='' />
</tr>
```

In javascript how can I perform a calculation?

Comment: Please post your JavaScript code.

Comment: So you want us to do it for you ? I see no code.

Comment: You must have done a few research first, before asking a question. I'm sure it would be easy to find good examples for this.

Comment: sorry guys wait I will post my code.

Comment: @user2585508 Since it's a javascript question, you should post your javascript code, not your PHP. SO help you with coding, it will not do the code for you. Try something, then we will be happy to help you.

Comment: ok sorry again. I will convert it to html. thanks for the reminders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to handle input update events is with `jQuery.on('input',...)`. You can use `parseFloat` and `parseInt` to get the values from the other inputs, `toFixed` to ensure the final value looks like currency (remove that if it's not needed), and provide a fallback of 0 in case something can't be parsed.

```
$('#qty, #price').on('input',function() {
    var qty = parseInt($('#qty').val());
    var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
    $('#total').val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hZ92k/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your textboxes a class name then loop through that class and add their value.

Let's say this is your text field

```
<input type="text" class="row-total">
```

And this is how you add them up

```
var total = 0;
$.each(".row-total", function(){
 total += $(this).val()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this thing you need to give your textbox1 and textbox2 a ("Comp") Class name
Ex:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1" class="Comp">
<input type="text" name="textbox2" class="Comp">
```

Then this will be the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Comp").change(function(){
        var total = 0.00;
        var textbox3= 0.00;    // this gonna be your third textbox
        $(".Comp").each(function(){
            total += parseFloat(this.value);
        });
        textbox3= $("#textbox3").val((total).toFixed(2));

    });
});
```

NOTE: Just edit the computation that suits to your need. This one only add the two textboxes (textbox1 and textbox2)